# Does Video.js support the media attribute to change the source according to the media query?

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I'm using video.js to serve html5 video in responsive layouts (using [Dave Rupert's tweak](http://daverupert.com/2012/05/making-video-js-fluid-for-rwd/) to alter the width and height to fit the container).
I'm now working on a site that will need to serve larger video where appropriate, and I'd like to use the media attribute to serve a different source video.
I could use javascript to change the source, but I'd like to be able to use the media query if possible, so that if JS is disabled, then a suitable video will still get served.

I've set up my code as follows:

```
<video id="lightTouchVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" poster="/Content/images/video-posters/light-touch.jpg" data-setup="{}">
<source src="/Content/video/light-touch-240p.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
<source src="/Content/video/light-touch-240p.webm" type='video/webm'>
<source src="/Content/video/light-touch-240p.ogv" type='video/ogv'>
<source src="/Content/video/light-touch-360p.mp4" type='video/mp4' media="all and (min-width:599px)">
<source src="/Content/video/light-touch-360p.webm" type='video/webm' media="all and (min-width:599px)">
<source src="/Content/video/light-touch-360p.ogv" type='video/ogv' media="all and (min-width:599px)">
</video>
```

I've tried using very obviously different videos for the two sources, and I just get whichever is listed in the source first. I've tried in the latest Firefox, Chrome and IE, so I don't think it's that the browser doesn't support the video media attribute (although it was rumoured to be considered for removal from the spec).

So, does video.js support the media attribute?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question, and from my tests I am afraid the response is no, which makes video.js unusable for targeting mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question, no. Video.js does not support the media attribute. Then again, the media attribute for source should only be used in a `<picture>` element [(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

But we can think outside of the box to solve your main problem:

> I'm now working on a site that will need to serve larger video where appropriate ...
>   I'd like to be able to use the media query if possible, so that if JS is disabled, then a suitable video will still get served.

So, thinking outside of the box and looking for a non-js way of solving it we can still use your idea of media queries, just not in the manner that you might've intended.

**[I have created an example here](http://codepen.io/Manbearpixel/details/gbMoqG/)** to demonstrate what I am going to explain.

---

You will need to append a specific class or ID name to various `<video>` tags each containing a source or proper quality/size for each specific device you wish to support. For this example, we will support smartphones (min 320px width), tablets (min 768px width), and desktops (min 1224px width).

From there, you can simply add the appropriate `@media` definitions in your CSS file to either hide or show the specific videos.

```
.mobile-res, .tablet-res, .desktop-res {
  display: none;
}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) */
@media (min-device-width : 320px) {
  .mobile-res {
    display: block;
  }
}


/* Tablets (portrait and landscape) */
@media (min-width : 768px) {
  .mobile-res {
    display: none;
  }
  .tablet-res {
    display: block;
  }
}

/* Desktops */
@media (min-width : 1224px) {
  .mobile-res,.tablet-res {
    display: none;
  }
  .desktop-res {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps solve your problem! Cheers!